# Why NSNotFound isn't -1 but NSIntegerMax

Tags: objective-c

NSNotFound is defined as NSIntegerMax, which has different values on 32-bit and 64-bit, this brings a lot of inconvenience for persistent and distributed env. Why not define it as -1?

PS, In ObjC and Cocoa, some indexOf... methods returns NSNotFound but some returns -1, is there a reason these results are inconsistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the answer probably isn't because it is sometimes returned as an unsigned value - in Objective-C conversions between signed and unsigned are effectively bit-copies so you can compare an unsigned to -1 and get the answer you expect (the values is all ones - -1 as signed, maximum integer as unsigned). See [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928715/is-there-any-way-to-store-unsigned-long-in-core-data).

So we come to your second part of the question, why in the inconsistency? Well *variety is the spice of life*, or put another way *there's nowt so queer as folk* - people are just inconsistent, no more complicated than that!

Answer (score 11):

This note from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNotFound) is probably relevant:

> #### Special Considerations
>
> Prior to Mac OS X v10.5, `NSNotFound` was defined as `0x7fffffff`. For 32-bit systems, this was effectively the same as `NSIntegerMax`. To support 64-bit environments, `NSNotFound` is now formally defined as `NSIntegerMax`. This means, however, that the value is different in 32-bit and 64-bit environments.

Answer (score 9):

Almost certainly because the some of the functions that return it are returning an *unsigned* value, such as [`NSIndexOfObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB):

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
//   ^
//   Note this!
```