# don't have access to synthesize property in animationDidStop method

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I have property:

```
@property NSMutableArray *fieldsArray;
@synthesize fieldsArray;
```

and in method I try to get something from this array:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{
    NSInteger firstBallIndex = [self.fieldsArray indexOfObject:self.firstBall];
}
```

But then I get error :

> NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index
>   2147483647 beyond bounds [0 .. 35]'

So array is not accesible.

How to do it visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the array itself, but instead with the value of `self.firstBall`. My best guess is that it's `nil`, which would make `firstBallIndex` `NSNotFound` (`2147483647`). Obviously, `2147483647` is beyond the bounds of your array, which then raises this error.

Depending on your implementation, you could do something like this:

```
if (firstBallIndex != NSNotFound)
    // which means that self.firstBall wasn't in your array in the first palce.
```

or

```
if ([self.fieldsArray containsObject:self.firstBall])
    // which basically does the same, but in a more stylish way.
```

Comment: Yes, You right - self.firstBall in nil when go to animationDidStop, I dont know why, because I don't reset this property, and before start animationDidStop method this property is set properly :/

Answer (score 1):

The array is accessible, it's just that the *index* that you are trying to pass is beyond bounds, probably because the number is negative.

The index `2147483647` looks like a negative 1 re-interpreted as a positive number. Make sure that `firstBallIndex` is between 0 and 35 before making a call to the `objectAtIndex:` method.

Since you use the `indexOfObject:` method to look for objects in `NSArray`, make sure that your objects properly implement the `isEqual:` method. Otherwise, `NSArray` will not be able to find your custom objects, unless you pass the exact instance to it.

Comment: `2147483647` is the value of the built-in `NSNotFound` constant, that's returned when `indexOfObject:` is unable to find the specified object.

Comment: @TimvanElsloo Right, which happens to have [the same bit pattern as -1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9338295/335858).